# cardinality of set $S$ where set $S$ is self orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a ﬁeld with ﬁve elements. Let $V$ be the $k-$vector space of $5\times1$ matrices with entries in k. Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ such that $u^{t}v =0$ for all $u$ and $v$ in $S$ here $u^t$ denotes the transpose of $u$ and $u^{t}v$ the usual matrix product. What is  the maximum possible cardinality of $S? $

**solution i tried**-
Given that set $S$ has elements of the from  of $5\times 1$ matrix let

$$u=\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\ 
    b\\ 
    c\\ 
    d\\ 
    e\end{pmatrix} and \;\;v=\begin{pmatrix}
    f\\ 
    g\\ 
    h\\ 
    i\\ 
    j\end{pmatrix}
$$
now according to question in set $S$ given that $u^tv=0$ i.e
$$af+bg+ch+id+ej=0$$ or we can say that $$af+bg+ch+id+ej$$ is multiple of $5$ i.e
$$af+bg+ch+id+ej=5N$$ where $N$ is some positive integer

after that i have no idea how to proccede further

Please help

Thank you

Comment: First, can you show that if $S$ is maximal then $S$ is a vector subspace, and thus has cardinality $5^r$ for some $r\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: How can i show that a set is maximal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I guess the maximal cardinality of $S$ is 6. Take any nonzero vector $v$ and (using Gram-Schmidt) construct an orthogonal basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $V$ from it. Let $S=\mathfrak{B}\cup 0$ be the union of the set of basis vectors (of which there are 5) and the zero vector. Obviously, there can't be a bigger set as each pair of vectors must be orthogonal. This works over all fields which makes me think that this is either a trick question or I have misunderstood it.